repeat_header_continued in markdown gives unwanted text outside the longtable
When I make a longtable with kableExtra in Quarto Markdown, it gives me unwanted LaTex code outside of the table at the very end.
I basically just followed kableExtra: Continued on Next Page for longtable.
I have tried to outcomment different things and it is only when I remove repeat_header_continued it doesn't give that extra bit but that defeats the point because I need that! :) Also I couldn't find any other with the same problem on Google.
Here's my code inside a .qmd document in RStudio:
---
title: "Test"
format: pdf
---

```{r}
#| echo: false
#| include: false
library(tidyverse)
library(kableExtra)

test <- data.frame(A = letters,
                   B = seq(1, length(letters), 1))
```

```{r}
#| label: tbl-longtable
#| tbl-cap: "This is a long table with a fault."
#| echo: false

test %>% 
  kbl(booktabs = T, digits = 0, format.args = list(big.mark = ".", decimal.mark = ","),
      linesep = "\\addlinespace",
      longtable = T) %>%
  kable_styling(latex_options = c("striped", "full_width", "HOLD_position", "repeat_header"),
                repeat_header_continued = T,
                position = "center") 
```


What am I doing wrong?
